# complex sigma notation in c

Tags: c, function, for-loop

[image]
[image]

I am trying to write a C program that computes this notation. I have been trying for hours but I cannot find my mistake. I must use three functions for combination, factorial, and power computing. Also, I cannot use another library than <stdio.h>.
I checked for combination, power, and factorial functions; there is no problem with them. I think the problem is in the for loops. For example, when I enter 5, I must get 100 something but instead, I get 0.19.
Here is my code. Can you please help me to find my mistake? Thanks a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n)
{

    int result_fact = 1, count;

    for (count = 1; count <= n; count++)
    {
        result_fact  = result_fact * count;
    }

    return result_fact;
}

int power(int x, int y)
{

    int result_pow = 1, count;

    for (count = 1; count <= y; count++)
    {
        result_pow *= x;
    }

    return result_pow;

}

int combination(int n, int r)
{

    int fact_n, fact_r, fact_n_r, result_com;

    fact_n = factorial(n);
    fact_r = factorial(r);
    fact_n_r = factorial(n - r);
    result_com = fact_n / (fact_n_r * fact_r);

    return result_com;

}

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, z, powe = 0, fact = 0, com = 0;
    double result_top = 0, result_top1 = 0, result_bottom = 0, result_bottom1 = 0, result;

    printf("Enter a n value >> ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (z = 1; z <= n - i; z++)
        {
            result_top += power(i, z);
        }
        result_top1 += result_top;
        result_top = 0;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; (j <= i); j++)
        {
            powe = power(j, n);
            com = combination(n, j);
            fact = factorial(n);
            result_bottom += ((powe * com) / fact);

        }

        result_bottom1 += result_bottom;

        result_bottom = 0;


    }

    result = result_top1 / result_bottom1;
    printf("%lf", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `((powe * com) / fact)` does integer division... maybe try `((powe * com) / (double)fact)` or define your variables as `double` to begin with (not sure if this is your problem, doesn't hurt to try). Also verify you're not causing overflow with all the multiplication and power around...

Comment: What input values are you failing on? Integer functions for power and factorial will overflow `int` very easily.

Comment: The symptoms of the error state you claim, including specific dependent input values, expected output values, and actual output values, should be [part of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66923901/edit).

Comment: I love C--I program in C for a living (on embedded devices). But it's important to choose the right tool for the job at hand. Out of all the dozens of languages I have programmed in over 30 years, C would be my dead last choice for this problem. Your factorial and power and combination functions will all silently overflow for any but the smallest n. And as mentioned, integer division forces you to do everything in double, despite the fact that the results should be integers.

Comment: If the power and factorial function don't overflow, the product `(powe * com)` might.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, this appears to be a homework assignment. Note the library use restriction.

Comment: your `n - i` for the `i^z` summation can be `0` which will make that cycle never run... `for (z = 1; z <= 0; z++) { /*nope*/ }`

Comment: Follow the code with a debugger, looking at the result of each step.

Comment: Best to post needed info _here_.

Comment: @TUANAGÜLER, please read [ask]. Please don't post links to images. We prefer text, but if you can't copy & paste that, then post the image, not a link to it.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Now that the equation is no longer posted here, it is hard to explain.  IAC, I recommend reviewing the equation and your code.  IMO, it did not match.

Comment: Since you have one large sigma and 2 little ones, shouldn't you have one outer `for` loop with 2 `for` loops inside it? Of the 2 inner loops, one should calculate the numerator and the other the denominator.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: You appear to want to delete this question because you realized that you couldn't share your homework question online. [This is not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802) as per site policy. Please don't keep trying to vandalize the post to get it deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary problems in your code:

- You use integer types even when doing divisions that produce non-integer results.
- You calculate a sum of the numerators and a sum of the denominators and divide those two sums. The mathematical expression says to calculate the sum of the fractions, not to sum the numerators and denominators separately.

Since we are going to need floating-point arithmetic for the divisions and there is some concern that the various functions may overflow the `int` type as `n` gets larger, let’s convert those to `double` first:

```
double factorial(int n)
{
    double result = 1;
    /*  Note:  When a loop variable like "count" is not needed outside the loop,
        declare it inside the loop, as is done below.
    */
    for (int count = 1; count <= n; ++count)
        result *= count;
    return result;
}


double power(int x, int y)
{
    double result = 1;
    for (int count = 1; count <= y; ++count)
        result *= x;
    return result;
}


double combination(int n, int r)
{
    //  Also declare other variables just where they are needed.
    double fact_n = factorial(n);
    double fact_r = factorial(r);
    double fact_n_r = factorial(n - r);
    return fact_n / (fact_n_r * fact_r);
}
```

While we are at it, let’s improve `combination`. Many of the factors in it cancel, so we can compute it with fewer operations. This may also avoid overflow or some rounding errors:

```
double combination(int n, int r)
{
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        result = result * (n-i) / (i+1);
    return result;
}
```

In `main`, the only thing we need to start is `n`, so let’s get rid of the other declarations:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a n value >> ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

Then we do want to start a sum, so we will define that and initialize it to zero. And we will start one loop on `i`, instead of having two:

```
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
```

Then we want a loop to calculate the numerator. Note that `z` is only needed inside the summation, which we implement with a loop, so we define it only inside the loop. The sum, in `top`, is needed outside the loop, so we define it outside the loop. Also note that, because we define `top` just here where we need it, inside the outer loop on `i`, we do not need to reset it after use. It will “go away” after each iteration of the outer loop and a new one will be created when the loop comes back to this `double top = 0;`. This handles the variables more neatly and avoids errors with leftover values not being erased:

```
        double top = 0;
        for (int z = 1; z <= n - i; ++z)
            top += power(i, z);
```

Then we need to calculate the denominator with a loop on `j`:

```
        double bottom = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            double j_power = power(j, n);
            double comb    = combination(n, j);
            double n_fact  = factorial(n);
            bottom += j_power * comb / n_fact;
        }
```

Now, still inside the loop on `i`, we take the quotient of the numerator and the denominator and add them to the sum:

```
        sum += top / bottom;
```

Then you can finish the loop, print the sum, and finish `main`:

```
    printf("%lf", sum);
}
```

Comment: @TUANAGÜLER: What is the maximum value of *n* your program must support? Do you have to use `int`, or can you use `long long int` or `uint64_t`?

Comment: For those small *n*, you can simply change the `double` I showed back to `int`.

Comment: @TUANAGÜLER: In C, an isolated `++i` or `i++` have the same effect; they increment `i`. (If they are not isolated—if the value is used, the result is different; one is the value after increment, one is the value before increment.) I make it habit to use the `++i` form because in C++ they can have different effects, when the operand is a class with complicated definitions for `++`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything. I have learned more tan the school.